# Adicionar dados em um arquivo txt

Tags: php, arquivo, fopen

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
$msg = "teste";
$myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "w");
fwrite($myfile, $msg."\n");
fclose($myfile);
```

Se eu mudar o valor da variável `$msg` ele abre o arquivo apaga a `$msg` anterior e a substitui pelo novo valor. Como posso manter os dois?

Exemplo de como eu quero a saída dentro do arquivo `txt`:

```
teste 
novo valor
```

Comment: Veja os [modos possíveis de abrir um arquivo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fopen.php#refsect1-function.fopen-parameters) e quais são as diferenças entre eles.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 6):

Você deve abrir o arquivo para adicionar e não para escrever:

```
$msg = "teste";
$myfile = fopen("lista.txt", "a");
fwrite($myfile, $msg."\n");
fclose($myfile);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/IO/AddData.php).

Pelo menos essa é a forma mais simples se só quer isso. Se quer fazer múltiplas operações então precisa de um algoritmo um pouco mais sofisticado para gerenciar o posicionamento no arquivo.

Outra possibilidade é usar o `file_put_contents()` com o argumento `FILE_APPEND`, assim evita o controle de arquivos.

Documentações:

- [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)
- [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

Answer (score 5):

A função [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) pode ser utilizada para fazer isso de uma forma mais simples. Segundo a documentação do PHP, esta função é a mesma coisa que chamar as funções fopen, fwrite e fclose:

> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose() successively to write data to a file.

Ou seja, esta função serve como uma forma simplificada de escrever dados em um arquivo.

```
$msg = 'teste' . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents('lista.txt', $msg, FILE_APPEND);
```

A constante `FILE_APPEND` serve para adicionar um novo conteúdo sem apagar o já existente. Portanto, caso a função seja executada de novo com um valor diferente, o valor `"teste"` não será apagado.

PS: Lembrando que a constante `PHP_EOL` serve para adicionar uma quebra de linha (independente do sistema operacional).